# acts-as-taggable-on gem is not persisting tag strings into edit or into show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I have tags on my `video` objects. I can submit tags when creating a new video via my form however they don't appear on my video show page, video index or video edit form, which makes me think they are not being presisted to the database but I'm unclear on what I as missing or doing wrong.

## models/video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { validates_presence_of :user, :post }
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

## views/videos/index.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @videos %>

<div class="" id="tag_cloud">
  <% tag_cloud Video.tag_counts.sort { |x, y| x.name <=> y.name }, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="">
  <% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <div class="">
      <%= link_to video.title, video_path(video) %></br >
      <%= content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{video.embed_id}") %>
      <p>Created by: <%= video.user.username %>, at: <%= video.created_at.strftime("%e, %b, %Y, %H:%M:%S %p") %></p>
      <% unless video.comments.last.nil? %>
        <%= video.comments.last.body %>
      <% end %>
      <p>
        Tags: <%= raw video.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(", ") %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## views/videos/_new.html.erb

```
<div class="">
  <% if current_user == @post.user || current_user.admin %>
    <h3>Add video</h3>
    <div class="">
      <%= form_for [@post, @video] do |f| %>
        <div class="">
          <%= f.label(:title, "Video Title") %></br >
          <%= f.text_field(:title) %>
        </div>

        <div class="">
          <%= f.label(:url, "Video Url") %></br >
          <%= f.text_field(:url) %>
        </div>

        <div class="">
          <%= f.label(:tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)") %></br >
          <%= f.text_field(:tag_list, multiple: true) %>
        </div>

        <div class="">
          <%= f.submit("Submit Video") %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

## views/videos/show.html.erb

```
<div class="video-show">
  <%= @video.title %>
  <%= content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/#{@video.embed_id}") %>
  <p>
    Tags: <%= @video.tag_list %>
  </p>
  <% if current_user == @video.user %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Video", edit_video_path(@video) %> |
    <%= link_to "Delete Video", video_path(@video), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |
  <% end %>
  <% if current_user == @video.user %>
    <%= link_to("Back to Log", post_path(@post)) %> |
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to("Back to Index", videos_path) %>
</div>
```

## controllers/videos_controller.rb

```
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @videos = Video.tagged_with(params[:tag]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10).order(created_at: "desc")
    else
      @videos = Video.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10).order(created_at: "desc")
    end
  end

  private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(
      :title,
      :url,
      :tag_list,
    )
  end
```

Comment: please try   acts_as_taggable_on :tags instead of    acts_as_taggable in your video model

Comment: I'll try this asap. I'm dealing with another self inflicted debacle at the moment.

Comment: That didn't fix it. I'm still getting the same issue of the tags not persisting.

Comment: Did tried to add a video from rails console ?? if yes , what the result ??

Comment: I have no problem saving videos. The problem is that the tags on the videos are not persisting.

Comment: can you join the logs when submitting a new video ?? may be there is some errors that didnt apear on the code ??